# Debbuging "attemp to index nil value"

Tags: c++, lua, gdb

I have a huge code which involves C++, Lua and the integration between both.

I invoke a C function that works with lua_State* and somewhere inside it I get an "attempt to index nil value". I don want to fill my code with traces.

Is there a way to make gdb break upon this error?

Comment: You should get a stack trace that points the line where the error has occurred.

Comment: Not if it happens in C code. One could try setting a breakpoint at `luaD_throw`.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into lua source I found out that the "attempt to index a nil value" message comes from the function `luaG_typeerror` (from `ldebug.c`).

So a break into `luaG_typerror` suffices.